# Which gives correct standard deviation ..numpy.std() or statistics.stdev()

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

```
import statistics
import numpy

speed = [99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86]
print(statistics.stdev(speed))
print(numpy.std(speed))`

#9.636336148089395
#9.258292301032677
```

why both answers are not same..since it's not same which answer is the correct standard deviation??? please explain someone

Answer (score 3):

For stdev of entire population as in `numpy.std()` use:

```
statistics.pstdev()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think both are correct. `statistics.stdev(speed)` makes the calculation using n-1 degrees of freedom and `numpy.std(speed)` uses n instead. If you're trying to estimate the standard deviation from a population using a sample of data, then you can use `statistics.stdev(speed)`.

Comment: Just checked np.std(X, ddof=1) returns the same as statistics.stdev.